# JQuery Mobile: Run javascript method on new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I have an app that allows users to win prizes. To win a prize they need to get to a page like this: `www.myUrl.com#isAWinner` where `#isAWinner` is my mobile page. I am worried that someone will think of just entering that url and going directly to the winner page without actually winning. To fix this I attempted to do this:

```
<!-- Show this if the user is a winner -->
<div id = "isAWinner" data-role = "page">
    <p>YOU WIN!!!</p>
    <!-- Invisible link -->
    <a href = "#beforeLogin" id = "goBack" class = "InvisibleLinks"></a>
    <!-- Ensures that the user does not just enter #isAWinner to the end of the URL -->
    <script type="text/javascript"> reallyAWinner()</script>
</div>

function reallyAWinner () {
    alert(isAWinner);
    //Check to see if they really are a winner
    if (isAWinner == false) {
        //Not really a winner. Send back to login
        $('#goBack').click();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `alert` is hit when the page initially loads, but if i try to go to that URL afterwords, then the method is not hit again.

Am I not understanding how JQuery mobile works? Will it only hit that `reallyAWinner()` method when the whole HTML page loads, and not when the `isAWinner` page loads? If so, is there another way I can check if the user is really a winner only when the `isAWinner` page loads?

**Edit**: here is a little more info. When I enter the method initially without loading the first page, the alert in `reallyAWinner()` will fire before an alert I have in my `document.ready` method, making the `$('#goBack').click();` not work (Because mobile is not loaded)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have enabled ajax method calls the function reallyAWinner() will be called when your initial page is called.

What you can do to call you function reallyAWinner() only when #isAWinner page is loaded you can register a "pageshow" event on the id of your page.

So you can do the following:

```
$('#isAWinner').live('pageshow', function () { reallyAWinner();  });
```

From jQueryMobile Documentation:

```
pageshow: Triggered on the page being shown, after its transition completes.
```

Comment: Thanks. That got it to load the method when that page loaded. One more question. I edited that method to contain this: `$.mobile.changePage('#beforeLogin');` where `beforeLogin` is the id of the page I want to redirect them to. When the method runs, that call will not work, but when I copy and paste that line into firebug, it does work. Am I missing something there?

Comment: I think you need to write $.mobile.changePage($('#beforeLogin')) as the first argument that changePage accepts is a jQuery Page.